# How to get some some specific result using MarkLogic search API

Tags: api, marklogic

I am new to MarkLogic and now I am trying to get some specific result of searching query.

More specifically, searching some word through search API and supposed to get a result of documents which include specific word.

No header information, no rank or any other meta data, just want to get documents as a result.

Is there any way to just one request and get documents as a result?
Or do I need to write some code to get specific result.

I'll be appreciated if you help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are accessing MarkLogic from outside, I'd have a look at a `POST` call to `/v1/search` with an `Accept` header of `multipart/mixed`. Details should be described here: https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/POST/v1/search

If running inside MarkLogic, you could consider using the low-level cts:search, which indeed returns documents directly. Keep in mind though that it won't paginate results, and it is usually unwise to return more than about 50 to 100 documents at once. It would just hog memory, and not allow for parallel processing.

HTH!

Comment: For examples and more details on Geert's REST suggestion, see  http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/bulk#id_65903.

Comment: Thanks, grtjn.I think I should understand like Elastic search thing... How do you think if I intend to make some table view like traditional RDB would do, Had I better use SQL through ODBC connection??

Comment: You can do add a so-called TDE template to create a tabular view on your documents, and you can query it with SQL through an ODBC connection if you like. For TDE, see: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/TDE, for ML SQL support, see: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/sql/intro

Comment: Thanks again, grtjn! So once a tabular view be created, can we handle it with QBE through REST client API?? I'm so appreciated your help.

Comment: Thank you sir. Your support rellay helps me.